# Does the bootstrap have a tree component?

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I am using angular 12 and bootstrap 4 (ng-bootstrap@10). I am having trouble finding a good component for building a tree. I only know about the existence of **ngx-treeview**, but I do not like it and as far as I understand it has not been supported for a year now.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good website that I use to explore bootstrap ideas: https://bootsnipp.com/tags/tree

if your looking for something angular based: https://codebyslice.com/angular-bootstrap-tree-component-4-step-tutorial/

Comment: My other go to site: https://codepen.io/akautsar/pen/yXZRdL

Comment: your fisrt link (and the comment link) use jQuery (bad idea)